# Cropping and Extracting ROI's from two different images in opencv

Tags: opencv, image-processing, object-detection

I have two Images 
[image: Image1:]

and the other image is:

[image: Image2]

In both images same object's corners have been highlighted by the green spot(image shape can be different). Now I want to extract the portion spotted with in green dots as rectangle using opencv. Any ideas

Comment: So you just want to find the rectangle around the two small green blobs?

Comment: no the object between two green blobs

Comment: do you have the coordinates of the two green circles?

Comment: @HumamHelfawi Yes I have the coordinates of the green circles

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the coordinates of the green dots.

```
cv::Mat your_image; //fill it
std::vector<cv::point> green_points; // fill it
auto rect=cv::boundingrect(green_points);
auto wanted_area=your_image(rect);
cv::imshow("wnated area",wanted_area);
```

Edit:

I have just notice that the two images are not ideintial there is a shift between them.. your problem is much comlex then.. do you have any information about the differences between them? is it 2d, 3d ? just shifting ?

Comment: I need to capture two images to extract object. one by pointing upper right corner and the other by point lower left corner. so most commonly there will only be a shift...

Comment: you should search for "Image registration" or "Image alignment". This is a big topic that can not be covered in an answer. But your case is some what simple so you may be able to make this registration very accurate with a simple code. Search For KLT algorithm